# Java Socket Server for Game Login/Authentication

Tags: java, sockets, authentication

I am currently working on a Java Application using the classes under java.net.* for a MMORPG I am creating. It'll be connected with a Unity3D Game (using .NET Sockets for TCP). I am unsure how to handle the login/authentication of players.

Suggestions? I was thinking about handling authentication this via a secure form over https, creating and storing a temporary login key in the database, and then sending the key back to the client, allotting them a minute to connect to a game server using the randomly generated key. Is this a secure and reliable solution, or is there something better I can do?

Server Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server extends Thread {

    public static final int MAX_CLIENTS = 500;

    private ServerSocket listener;
    protected ArrayList<Client> clients;

    public Server(int listenPort) throws IOException {
        listener = new ServerSocket(
                listenPort, MAX_CLIENTS,
                InetAddress.getLocalHost()
        );

        clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                Client client = new Client(socket, this);
                clients.add(client);

                new Thread(client).start();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        new Server(4428).start();
    }
}
```

Client Class

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client implements Runnable {

    private Socket socket;
    private Server server;
    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;

    public Client(Socket sock, Server serv) {
        socket = sock;
        server = serv;
        in = null;
        out = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

            while (true) {
                // Read Data with read()
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    public void read() throws IOException {
    }

    public void send(String data) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code. It helps if you show us what you've done so far.

Comment: I posted what I have so far. I haven't started anything with authentication yet, as that can be done using a login server, or as a www form from Unity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using HTTPS for login and for important account actions (buy/sell/transfer items).  When the client logins to the server over HTTPS the server should generate a long (64-128 bytes) random session id that is stored in the database.  Also generate a temporary one-time authentication token (long random value) for the client's TCP connection.

The reason for using HTTPS is to help stop [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks from stealing the users in game assets.

If the traffic between client & server is low you could use a TLS socket instead of a normal TCP socket.  Just make sure to have the client validate(Signed by a trusted CA and that the domain matches) the server's certificate.

Even if you use HTTPS for important actions a MITM attack could still mess with the users actions (moving, attacking, chat) or change what the user sees (hide monsters or other users).